# Importing maven library and maven sample in Eclipse project

Tags: java, android, maven, nfc, maven-plugin

I know its quiet irrelevant question but I have banged my head too much but found no solution for that..I am building android app which can read contents from NFC cards.I am using this library to perform my job https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment .But there is also the sample app for this library in this link which I can't import in my Eclipse.Also I need to know how to import this library in my project.

Please help me out.

Regards
BSOFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a maven project (indicated by the presence of pom.xml), so you need to first install maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Then, navigate to the library root directory and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate eclipse project files. You can then import the library into eclipse as a standard Java Project.

To import the library into your own project, run `mvn install` from the library root directory to build a jar and install it to your local maven repository. In your local project, you can then either add a dependency on the jar (find it in your maven repository, `~/.m2/`), or use maven in your own project and add the library as a dependency in your pom.xml.

Comment: where to run mvn eclipse:eclipse ?

Comment: From the root directory of the library (where there is a pom.xml), maven will read the pom and use it to generate the eclipse project files.

Comment: Assuming the op has a uptodate eclipse `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is not necessary. Just use the import from within Eclipse.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not getting you ..Please can you elaborate and give me step by step guide.Am still stuck and even unable to install maven so far.. :'(

Comment: just install maven from http://apache.mirrors.timporter.net/maven/maven-3/3.2.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.3-bin.zip - once it is installed, you should find that the `mvn` command is available on the command line.

Comment: hey @Josh after making jar of the library how I can add it to my own project? please help

Comment: the easiest way is just to add the jar as a library dependency on your build path... alternatively, if you set up your own project to use maven then you could just add the dependency to your pom